# R Populate matrix with a list of indices

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I try to create an adjacency matrix M from a list pList containing the indices that have to be equal to 1 in the matrix M.
For example, M is a 10x5 matrix
The variable pList contains 5 elements, each one is a vector of indices

Example :

```
s <- list("1210", c("254", "534"), "254", "534", "364")
M <- matrix(c(rep(0)),nrow = 5, ncol = length(unique(unlist(s))), dimnames=list(1:5,unique(unlist(s))))
```

Actually, my too simple solution is the brutal one with a for loop over rows of the matrix :

```
for (i in 1:nrow(M)){
      M[i, as.character(s[[i]])] <- 1 
}
```

So that the expected result is :

```
M
  1210 254 534 364
1    1   0   0   0
2    0   1   1   0
3    0   1   0   0
4    0   0   1   0
5    0   0   0   1
```

The problem is that I have to manipulate matrices with several thousands of lines and it takes too much time.
I am not a "apply" expert but I wonder if there is a quicker solution

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 3):

We can convert the `list` to a `matrix` of `row/column` index, use that index to assign the elements in 'M' to 1.

```
M[as.matrix(stack(setNames(s, seq_along(s)))[,2:1])] <- 1
M
#   1210 254 534 364
#1    1   0   0   0
#2    0   1   1   0
#3    0   1   0   0
#4    0   0   1   0
#5    0   0   0   1
```

Or instead of using `stack` to convert to a `data.frame`, we can `unlist` the 's' to get the column index, `cbind` with row index created by replicating the sequence of `list` with `length` of each `list` element (using `lengths`) and assign the elements in 'M' to 1.

```
M[cbind(rep(seq_along(s), lengths(s)), unlist(s))] <- 1
```

---

Or yet another option would be to create a `sparseMatrix`

```
library(Matrix)
Un1 <- unlist(s)
sparseMatrix(i = rep(seq_along(s), lengths(s)),
             j=as.integer(factor(Un1, levels = unique(Un1))),
             x=1)
```